# Polite way to tell Guest about Door is not opening

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one from below sentences is correct way to tell guest that the door is not opening?

> a) This door doesn't open.
>
> b) This door doesn't get opened/open.

Does above Sentences mean the same thing? or its grammatically worn? or rude way of saying?

Comment: Can you tell us who is the person talking to the guest? Hotel employee/manager? Home owner? Restaurant staff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both OK to be used. The meaning is slightly different. If you worry about (not) being rude, you can also add the reason. Consider the following.

> This door is locked and must not be open.

(This actually happened to me, while I was a guest; once it was a room door, another time it as a wardrobe door. The host was showing me around upon arrival.)

> This door is broken and must not be open, in order to avoid accidents.

(This implies that the hinges are broken and are not able to hold the door while it is open.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Are my versions grammatically correct? also what is the slight difference in meaning?

Comment: In the first sentence, we don't know why it does not open, there is no reason specified. In the second sentence, some defect is implied. In the second sentence, use "open". Everything else is OK. Hopefully, I am not wrong about the meanings :D

Comment: “The door must not be open” is not idiomatic. “The door should not be opened” would be better, especially if the door is currently closed.

Answer (score 2):

(a) means the door is stuck.

(b) is an odd way of saying it is forbidden to open the door.